# Waiting for image to load in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, load, wait

I'm making an Ajax call which returns me some info including an image path.

I prepare all this information in my HTML which will be displayed as a kind of popup. I just toggle the visibility of by popup div from hidden to visible.

To set the position of my popup div, I have to calculate depending on the height of the image. So, I have to wait for the image to load to know its dimension before setting position and switching visibility to visible.

I tried tricks with recursion, setTimeout, complete img property, while loop... without success.

So, how can I do this? Maybe I should return dimensions in my Ajax call.

Comment: why doesn't it work with the `Image.complete` property?

Answer (score 162, accepted):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { alert("Height: " + this.height); }
img.src = "http://path/to/image.jpg";
```

Note that it's important to do it in the order above: **First** attach the handler, **then** set the `src`. If you do it the other way around, and the image is in cache, you may miss the event. JavaScript is run on a single thread in browsers (unless you're using web workers), but *browsers* are not single-threaded. It's perfectly valid for the browser to see the `src`, identify the resource is available, load it, trigger the event, look at the element to see if it has any handlers that need to be queued for callback, not see any, and complete the event processing, all between the `src` line and the line attaching the handler. (The callbacks wouldn't happen between the lines if they were registered, they'd wait in the queue, but if there aren't any, the event isn't required to wait.)

Comment: Grat! BTW: i'm quite ignorant on the AJAX subject, but just in case an image got with AJAX is cached in the same way of an image written dierctly into HTML code, you could eventually add this in order to avoid browser's image caching (obviously only if you need it): img.src="http://path/to/image.jpg"+"?refresh="+new Date().getTime();

Comment: @Marco Or set `cache: false` on the XHR :)  Although I don't think it's relevant here because the AJAX call is returning a URL to the image, not the image itself.  But yes I suppose he could still use a random query string value to make sure no user-agent caching occurs.

Comment: Can you add an event listener as well, or is replacing `onload` the way?

Comment: @IQAndreas: You could use `img.addEventListener("load", ...)`, yes. (Or `img.attachEvent("onload", ...)` on old IE).

Comment: Does it matter if I change the order of second and third line?

Comment: It doesn't actually answer the question: how to wait for image to load (obviously in current thread).

Comment: Can I do this without creating an image element from Javascript?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The onload function is executed even before setting img.src.

Comment: This doesn't work for me either. Can you please update your answer?

Answer (score 18):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342181/6243352) is outdated but does show the basic [`Image#onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Mozilla/XUL/Attribute/image.onload) callback approach. Nowadays, you'll likely want to promisify the image load to avoid callback hell.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490149/6243352) is a good shot at promisifying the image onload handler, but is missing some key points as [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript/66180709#comment117004330_60490149) indicates.

Here's another promisification of `Image` that is a bit more general. Rejecting in the `onerror` handler and passing the actual image object into the resolver are important to make the function minimally reusable.

Improvements might include additional parameters (such as `crossOrigin`, for example). A `settings` object or providing an `Image` as a parameter is another approach to generalize the function (setting `src` fires the request, so that should go last after handlers have been added).

```js
const loadImage = src =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = src;
  });

loadImage("https://picsum.photos/85/150").then(image => 
  console.log(image, `\nloaded? ${image.complete}`)
);
```

With the above function, [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) can be used to load a batch of images in parallel ([`Promise.allSettled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/allSettled) is useful if you want to keep going even if some images don't load).

```js
const loadImage = src =>
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = src;
  });

const imageUrls = [
  "https://picsum.photos/85/150",
  "https://picsum.photos/85/130",
  "https://picsum.photos/85/110",
];
Promise.all(imageUrls.map(loadImage)).then(images => {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  images.forEach((image, i) =>
    ctx.drawImage(image, i * 90, 0, image.width, image.height)
  );
});
```

Answer (score 13):

If you use jQuery, you can use its [load](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) event.

Have a look at the example:

```
$('img.userIcon').load(function(){
    if($(this).height() > 100) {
        $(this).addClass('bigImg');
    }
});
```

Comment: -1: no mention of jQuery in the question, so an answer like this can be quite confusing.

Comment: Please also note the following caveats with the load method when used with images (taken from http://api.jquery.com/load-event/): 

 > It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
 > It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
 > It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
 > Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache

Answer (score 9):

#### Function to wait for image, that is *already in HTML*.

###### Promise example. Does not rejects just waits for load or fail:

```js
function waitForImage(imgElem) {
    return new Promise(res => {
        if (imgElem.complete) {
            return res();
        }
        imgElem.onload = () => res();
        imgElem.onerror = () => res();
    });
}



// test
(async () => {
  const img = document.querySelector('img');
  // to not to cache in the test, set src dynamically
  img.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71094909be9f40bd576b1974a74966aa?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';

  console.log('height before', img.naturalHeight); // 0
  await waitForImage(img);
  console.log('height after', img.naturalHeight); // 48
})();
```

```html
<img src=""/>
```

###### Version with reject, if you need to know, if its failed:

```js
function waitForImage(imgElem) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        if (imgElem.complete) {
            return res();
        }
        imgElem.onload = () => res();
        imgElem.onerror = () => rej(imgElem);
    });
}



// test
(async () => {
  const img = document.querySelector('#rightone');
  // to not to cache in the test, set src dynamically
  img.src = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/71094909be9f40bd576b1974a74966aa?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1';

  console.log('height before', img.naturalHeight); // 0
  await waitForImage(img); // success
  console.log('height after', img.naturalHeight); // 48

  try {
    const failImg = document.querySelector('#wrongone');
    failImg.src = 'https://wrongimage';
    await waitForImage(failImg); // rejects after some time
  } catch(e) {
    console.log('failed to load image', e)
  }


})();
```

```html
<img id="rightone" src="">
<img id="wrongone" src="">
```

Answer (score 3):

just wrap your image onload in a function with a promise and then call it with await.

```
async drawImg(ctx, image){

    return new Promise(resolve => {

          image.onload = function () {
                ctx.drawImage(image, 10, 10, 200, 180);
                resolve('resolved');
             }

    });

  }
```

it should work just fine

Comment: The `async` keyword here is unnecessary--returning a promise is enough for the caller to `await` it. It's also a good idea to promisify the onerror handler with `reject()` so the caller can catch the error if the load fails. Last suggestion: you could pass the image object itself to `resolve(this)` so that the caller can draw the image or do what they want with it.

Answer (score 3):

How about the window load event?

```
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  //do stuff with images
});
```

or

```
window.onload = (event) => {
  //do stuff with images
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

This worked for me where I needed the browser to calculate the size of the images before running a layout script.

Comment: This doesn't quite seem to answer the question, as there are many times that an image can be loaded after the page itself loads, including this example. The onload event on window does wait for images to be loaded, but only for the initial page load. In the context of this question, the onload event should be tied directly to the image element that is being loaded instead.

Answer (score -2):

I had a slow CAPTCHA (1st_image) image loading on my page and I wanted to display another image (2nd_image) only AFTER the CAPTCHA image (1st_image) is loaded. So I had to wait for the CAPTCHA (1st_image) image to load first.

Here is the solution that works perfectly fine to wait for an image to load first and then load another image (don't forget to display a "please wait!" image while they are waiting for other image to load):

```
<script>
    function checkImageLoad() {
        if (document.getElementById("1st_image").complete == true) {
            console.log("1st_image Loaded!");
        }
        document.getElementById("2nd_image").src = "http://example.org/2nd_image.png";
    }
</script>
<body onload="checkImageLoad();">
<img id="1st_image" src="http://example.org/1st_image.png">
<img id="2nd_image" src="http://example.org/loading_please_wait.gif">
```

Either the Internet speed is slow or fast, and the browser will wait for the whole page to load with all the images (even if they are linked externally) and then execute the function, so the second image is displayed only after the first image loads fine.

**Advanced note: You can use a web page URL in the "src" of the image to load a web page first and then show the image. The purpose is to load the cookie from the external webpage which might effect the second image displayed (like CAPTCHA)**.