# Getting the width and height of a div after it finished loading

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get the width and height of a div after it finishes loading by using javascript, but it's getting the width and height of the div BEFORE the image finishes loading. What can I do to fix this?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
var width = document.getElementById("image").offsetWidth;
var height = document.getElementById("image").offsetHeight;
alert(width+":"+height);
</script>
```

```css
#image {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'image'>
<img src = 'http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png'>
</div>
```

**Result:**

```
634:2
```

**Expected Result:**

```
634:(More Than 2 Pixels)
```

Comment: Put a `load` event listener to the `img` and get the height there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for image to load in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Use .load to wait till that element is loaded in the dom

```
$("#image").load(function() {
  var width = document.getElementById("image").offsetWidth;
  var height = document.getElementById("image").offsetHeight;
  alert(width+":"+height);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a javascript snippet

**Note: Your width is 50% so depends on the size of the window, your div width will change.hence you wouldn't obtain  a fixed width unless you use an absolute unit of measurement**

```js
var width=height=null;
function handler(){
width=document.getElementById('image').offsetWidth;
height=document.getElementById('image').offsetHeight;
alert('width:'+width+',height: '+height);
}
document.getElementById('actual_image').addEventListener('load',handler,false);
```

```css
#image {
border: 1px solid red;
width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'image'>
<img id="actual_image" src = 'http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png'>
</div>
```