# Why doesn't my image draw in Canvas ? No error in my code

Tags: javascript

I got this sample of code which i was working on it, i got a trouble with because my image angular doesn't appear on the web browser, i can't understand what's my mistake, thanks in advance for your help.

```
<html>

<script>

var canvas,context;

function init(){


canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
monImg = new Image();
monImg.src="img/angular.png";
context.drawImage(monImg,300,300);


}


window.onload=init();


</script>

 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
 </body>
```

Comment: Is `img/angular.png` found and loaded in the browser's network tab?

Comment: `<script>` tag should be in the end. Just before `</body>`.

Comment: Yes the img/angular.png is found by the web browser

Comment: Yes i tried to move the script it doesn't change anything unfortunately

Comment: There’s no way that works as written, since `window.onload = init()` just calls `init` right away. `canvas` won’t exist yet and `canvas.getContext('2d')` will throw an error without getting to the image part. Please show your full HTML in the right order.

Comment: The canvas element cannot be found because the script is looking for it in the DOM before it's actually there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting for image to load in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript)

Comment: No it's another question because the onload doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a handler for the Image onload where you call drawImage() such as:

```
 <html>

 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1920" height="1080"></canvas>
 </body>

<script>

var canvas,context;

function init(){

canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
monImg = new Image();
monImg.src="img/angular.png";
monImg.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(monImg,300,300);
}

}


window.onload=init();


</script>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript).

You have to wait for the image to load before you do anything with it. The easiest way is:

```
monImg = new Image();
monImg.onLoad = function() {
    context.drawImage(monImg, 300, 300);
}
monImg.src = "img/angular.png";
```