# Get Onload of a XHR call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, pre-signed-url

The goal or aim is to put a dummy url untill the actual xhr call loads.The original call is S3.getsignedurl() which returns a url and that url is called in respective html tags; i.e. Image in , PDF files in .
I need to find out when that url is loaded and then switch the images from the temporary to the actual one. Any ideas?

Comment: I hope you are looking something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2342181/9669724

Comment: Please add some code you are currently using so we can assist effectively :)

Comment: so ... `someXhrInstance.addEventListener('load', function(e) { ... do your thing })`