# how to import a height map in WebGL

Tags: javascript, webgl, heightmap

I know that in theory you have to first find the coordinates on the height map like (x = `width HM / width Terrain * x Terrain`) and y coordinate (`y = height HM / height Terrain * y Terrain`) and after getting the location on the height map, we get the actual height by `min_height + (colorVal / (max_color - min_color) * *max_height - min_height`) thus returning a Z value for a particular segment.

But how can i actually import the height map and take its parameters? I'm writing in javascript with no additional libraries (three,babylon).

**edit**

Currently i'm hardcoding the z values based on x and y ranges:

```
    Plane.prototype.modifyGeometry=function(x,y){
    if((x>=0&&x<100)&&(y>=0&&y<100)){
        return 25;
    }
    else if((x>=100&&x<150)&&(y>=100&&y<150)){
        return 20;
    }
    else if((x>=150&&x<200)&&(y>=150&&y<200)){
        return 15;
    }
    else if((x>=200&&x<250)&&(y>=200&&y<250)){
        return 10;
    }
    else if((x>=250&&x<300)&&(y>=250&&y<300)){
        return 5;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
```

** edit **

i can get a flat grid (or with randomly generated heights), but as soon as i add the image data, i get a blank screen(no errors though). Here is the code (i changed it up a bit):

```
var gl;
var canvas;

var img = new Image();
// img.onload = run;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/heightmap-96x64.png';


var gridWidth;
var gridDepth;
var gridPoints = [];
var gridIndices = [];
var rowOff = 0;
var rowStride = gridWidth + 1;
var numVertices = (gridWidth * 2 * (gridDepth + 1)) + (gridDepth * 2 * (gridWidth + 1));


//creating plane
function generateHeightPoints() {

    var ctx = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"); //using 2d canvas to read image
    ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

    gridWidth = imgData.width - 1;
    gridDepth = imgData.height - 1;

    for (var z = 0; z <= gridDepth; ++z) {
        for (var x = 0; x <= gridWidth; ++x) {
            var offset = (z * imgData.width + x) * 4;
            var height = imgData.data[offset] * 10 / 255;
            gridPoints.push(x, height, z);
        }
    }
}

function generateIndices() {
for (var z = 0; z<=gridDepth; ++z) {
    rowOff = z*rowStride;
    for(var x = 0; x<gridWidth; ++x) {
        gridIndices.push(rowOff+x,rowOff+x+1);
    }
}

for (var x = 0; x<=gridWidth; ++x) {
    for(var z = 0; z<gridDepth; ++z) {
        rowOff = z * rowStride;
        gridIndices.push(rowOff+x,rowOff+x+rowStride);
    }
}
}
//init

//program init
window.onload = function init()
{ 
canvas = document.getElementById( "gl-canvas" );


gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );
if ( !gl ) { alert( "WebGL isn't available" ); }

gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

var program = initShaders( gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader" );
gl.useProgram( program );




generateHeightPoints();
generateIndices();


var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), 
gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    var indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(gridIndices), 
 gl.STATIC_DRAW);

var vPosition = gl.getAttribLocation( program, "vPosition" );
gl.vertexAttribPointer( vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0 );
gl.enableVertexAttribArray( vPosition );

var matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'matrix');

var m4 = twgl.m4;
var projection = m4.perspective(60 * Math.PI / 180, gl.canvas.clientWidth / 
gl.canvas.clientHeight, 0.1, 100);
var cameraPosition = [-18, 15, -10];
var target = [gridWidth / 2, -10, gridDepth / 2];
var up = [0, 1, 0];
var camera = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);
var view = m4.inverse(camera);
var mat = m4.multiply(projection, view);

gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc, false, mat);




 render();




}



function render() {


gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, numVertices, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);



gl.drawElements(gl.LINES,numVertices,gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,0);
requestAnimFrame(render);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "import a height map". There is no standard format for a height map so there is no answer for "import a height map". Maybe you mean read a CSV file? A PNG file? A JPEG? a JSON file?

Comment: You're not [waiting for the image to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript) before trying to use it.

Comment: @gman i figured window.onload waits until everything (including images) is loaded. When i only use the run function at img.onload, i get a TypeError (cannot read property of null) here:  `gl = WebGLUtils.setupWebGL( canvas );` , but when i first use run, then window.onload init()... i still only get a blank screen

Comment: The code you posted is not waiting for window.onload when using the image. It's calling `init` on onload but the image itself is used immediately. Further you compute `rowStride` out initializing `gridWidth`. I'd suggect you [learn to use a debugger and step through your code](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript). Note: I haven't used windon.onload in > 8 years. It's not common and not the recommended way to do things in 2019.

Answer (score 3):

You basically just make a grid of points and change the Z values.

First a flat grid

```js
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const vs = `
attribute vec4 position;
uniform mat4 matrix;
void main() {
  gl_Position = matrix * position;
}
`;
const fs = `
precision highp float;
void main() {
  gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
}
`;

const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
const positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
const matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'matrix');

const gridWidth = 40;
const gridDepth = 40;
const gridPoints = [];
for (let z = 0; z <= gridDepth; ++z) {
  for (let x = 0; x <= gridWidth; ++x) {
    gridPoints.push(x, 0, z);
  }
}

const gridIndices = [];
const rowStride = gridWidth + 1;
// x lines
for (let z = 0; z <= gridDepth; ++z) {
  const rowOff = z * rowStride;
  for (let x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
    gridIndices.push(rowOff + x, rowOff + x + 1);
  }
}
// z lines
for (let x = 0; x <= gridWidth; ++x) {
  for (let z = 0; z < gridDepth; ++z) {
    const rowOff = z * rowStride;
    gridIndices.push(rowOff + x, rowOff + x + rowStride);
  }
}

const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(gridIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

const m4 = twgl.m4;
const projection = m4.perspective(
  60 * Math.PI / 180,   // field of view
  gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, // aspect
  0.1,  // near
  100,  // far
);
const cameraPosition = [-gridWidth / 8, 10, -gridDepth / 8];
const target = [gridWidth / 2, -10, gridDepth / 2];
const up = [0, 1, 0];
const camera = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);
const view = m4.inverse(camera);
const mat = m4.multiply(projection, view);

gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
gl.vertexAttribPointer(
    positionLoc,  // location
    3,            // size
    gl.FLOAT,     // type
    false,        // normalize
    0,            // stride
    0,            // offset
);

gl.useProgram(program);
gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc, false, mat);

const numVertices = (gridWidth * 2 * (gridDepth + 1)) +
                    (gridDepth * 2 * (gridWidth + 1));
gl.drawElements(
    gl.LINES,           // primitive type
    numVertices,        //
    gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,  // type of indices
    0,                  // offset
);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Grid with height map.

Here's a gray scale image we can use as a height map

[image]

Read it by loading a img, drawing to a 2D canvas, calling getImageData. Then just read the red values for height.

```js
const img = new Image();
img.onload = run;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/heightmap-96x64.png';


function run() {
  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  uniform mat4 matrix;
  void main() {
    gl_Position = matrix * position;
  }
  `;
  const fs = `
  precision highp float;
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(0, 1, 0, 1);
  }
  `;

  const program = twgl.createProgram(gl, [vs, fs]);
  const positionLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(program, 'position');
  const matrixLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'matrix');

  // use a canvas 2D to read the image
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  const gridWidth = imgData.width - 1;
  const gridDepth = imgData.height - 1;
  const gridPoints = [];
  for (let z = 0; z <= gridDepth; ++z) {
    for (let x = 0; x <= gridWidth; ++x) {
      const offset = (z * imgData.width + x) * 4;
      // height 0 to 10
      const height = imgData.data[offset] * 10 / 255;
      gridPoints.push(x, height, z);
    }
  }

  const gridIndices = [];
  const rowStride = gridWidth + 1;
  // x lines
  for (let z = 0; z <= gridDepth; ++z) {
    const rowOff = z * rowStride;
    for (let x = 0; x < gridWidth; ++x) {
      gridIndices.push(rowOff + x, rowOff + x + 1);
    }
  }
  // z lines
  for (let x = 0; x <= gridWidth; ++x) {
    for (let z = 0; z < gridDepth; ++z) {
      const rowOff = z * rowStride;
      gridIndices.push(rowOff + x, rowOff + x + rowStride);
    }
  }

  const positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(gridPoints), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  const indexBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indexBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, new Uint16Array(gridIndices), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  const m4 = twgl.m4;
  const projection = m4.perspective(
    60 * Math.PI / 180,   // field of view
    gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight, // aspect
    0.1,  // near
    100,  // far
  );
  const cameraPosition = [-10, 10, -10];
  const target = [gridWidth / 2, -10, gridDepth / 2];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const camera = m4.lookAt(cameraPosition, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);
  const mat = m4.multiply(projection, view);

  gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLoc);
  gl.vertexAttribPointer(
      positionLoc,  // location
      3,            // size
      gl.FLOAT,     // type
      false,        // normalize
      0,            // stride
      0,            // offset
  );

  gl.useProgram(program);
  gl.uniformMatrix4fv(matrixLoc, false, mat);

  const numVertices = (gridWidth * 2 * (gridDepth + 1)) +
                      (gridDepth * 2 * (gridWidth + 1));
  gl.drawElements(
      gl.LINES,           // primitive type
      numVertices,        //
      gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT,  // type of indices
      0,                  // offset
  );
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Then instead of making a grid of lines make a grid of triangles. There's lots of ways to do that. You could put 2 triangle per grid square. This code put's 4. You also need to generate normals. I copied the code to generate normals from [this article](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-geometry-lathe.html) which is fairly generic normal generating code.  Being a grid you could make a grid specific normal generator which would be faster since being a grid you know which vertices are shared.

This code is also using [twgl](https://twgljs.org) because WebGL is too verbose but it should be clear how to do it in plain WebGL from reading the names of the twgl functions.

```js
'use strict';

/* global twgl, m4, requestAnimationFrame, document */

const img = new Image();
img.onload = run;
img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/images/heightmap-96x64.png';


function run() {
  // use a canvas 2D to read the image
  const ctx = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
  ctx.canvas.width = img.width;
  ctx.canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);


  function getHeight(offset) {
    const v =  imgData.data[offset * 4]; // x4 because RGBA
    return v * 10 / 255; // 0 to 10
  }

  // first generate a grid of triangles, at least 2 or 4 for each cell
  // 
  //    2          4
  // +----+     +----+ 
  // |   /|     |\  /|
  // |  / |     | \/ |
  // | /  |     | /\ |
  // |/   |     |/  \|
  // +----+     +----+ 
  //

  const positions = [];
  const texcoords = [];
  const indices = [];

  const cellsAcross = imgData.width - 1;
  const cellsDeep = imgData.height - 1;
  for (let z = 0; z < cellsDeep; ++z) {
    for (let x = 0; x < cellsAcross; ++x) {
      const base0 = z * imgData.width + x;
      const base1 = base0 + imgData.width;

      const h00 = getHeight(base0);       const h01 = getHeight(base0 + 1);
      const h10 = getHeight(base1);
      const h11 = getHeight(base1 + 1);
      const hm = (h00 + h01 + h10 + h11) / 4;

      const x0 = x;
      const x1 = x + 1;
      const z0 = z;
      const z1 = z + 1;

      const ndx = positions.length / 3;
      positions.push(
        x0, h00, z0,
        x1, h01, z0,
        x0, h10, z1,
        x1, h11, z1,
        (x0 + x1) / 2, hm, (z0 + z1) / 2,
      );
      const u0 = x / cellsAcross;
      const v0 = z / cellsDeep;
      const u1 = (x + 1) / cellsAcross;
      const v1 = (z + 1) / cellsDeep;
      texcoords.push(
        u0, v0,
        u1, v0,
        u0, v1,
        u1, v1,
        (u0 + u1) / 2, (v0 + v1) / 2,
      );

  //         
  //      0----1 
  //      |\  /|
  //      | \/4|
  //      | /\ |
  //      |/  \|
  //      2----3 

      indices.push(
        ndx, ndx + 4, ndx + 1,
        ndx, ndx + 2, ndx + 4,
        ndx + 2, ndx + 3, ndx + 4,
        ndx + 1, ndx + 4, ndx + 3,
      );
    }
  }

  const maxAngle = 2 * Math.PI / 180;  // make them facetted
  const arrays = generateNormals({
    position: positions,
    texcoord: texcoords,
    indices,
  }, maxAngle);


  const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');

  const vs = `
  attribute vec4 position;
  attribute vec3 normal;
  attribute vec2 texcoord;

  uniform mat4 projection;
  uniform mat4 modelView;

  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;

  void main() {
    gl_Position = projection * modelView * position;
    v_normal = mat3(modelView) * normal;
    v_texcoord = texcoord;
  }
  `;

  const fs = `
  precision highp float;

  varying vec3 v_normal;
  varying vec2 v_texcoord;
  varying float v_modelId;

  void main() {
    vec3 lightDirection = normalize(vec3(1, 2, -3));  // arbitrary light direction

    float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
    gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(0,1,0) * l, 1);
  }
  `;

  // compile shader, link, look up locations
  const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

  // make some vertex data
  // calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData for each array
  const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, arrays);

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // seconds

    twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

    const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
    const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
    const near = 0.1;
    const far = 100;
    const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);

    const eye = [0, 10, 25];
    const target = [0, 0, 0];
    const up = [0, 1, 0];
    const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
    const view = m4.inverse(camera);
    let modelView = m4.yRotate(view, time);
    modelView = m4.translate(modelView, imgData.width / -2, 0, imgData.height / -2)

    gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);

    // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
    twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);

    // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
    twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
      projection,
      modelView,
    });  

    // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
    twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);


  function generateNormals(arrays, maxAngle) {
    const positions = arrays.position;
    const texcoords = arrays.texcoord;

    // first compute the normal of each face
    let getNextIndex = makeIndiceIterator(arrays);
    const numFaceVerts = getNextIndex.numElements;
    const numVerts = arrays.position.length;
    const numFaces = numFaceVerts / 3;
    const faceNormals = [];

    // Compute the normal for every face.
    // While doing that, create a new vertex for every face vertex
    for (let i = 0; i < numFaces; ++i) {
      const n1 = getNextIndex() * 3;
      const n2 = getNextIndex() * 3;
      const n3 = getNextIndex() * 3;

      const v1 = positions.slice(n1, n1 + 3);
      const v2 = positions.slice(n2, n2 + 3);
      const v3 = positions.slice(n3, n3 + 3);

      faceNormals.push(m4.normalize(m4.cross(m4.subtractVectors(v1, v2), m4.subtractVectors(v3, v2))));
    }

    let tempVerts = {};
    let tempVertNdx = 0;

    // this assumes vertex positions are an exact match

    function getVertIndex(x, y, z) {

      const vertId = x + "," + y + "," + z;
      const ndx = tempVerts[vertId];
      if (ndx !== undefined) {
        return ndx;
      }
      const newNdx = tempVertNdx++;
      tempVerts[vertId] = newNdx;
      return newNdx;
    }

    // We need to figure out the shared vertices.
    // It's not as simple as looking at the faces (triangles)
    // because for example if we have a standard cylinder
    //
    //
    //      3-4
    //     /   \
    //    2     5   Looking down a cylinder starting at S
    //    |     |   and going around to E, E and S are not
    //    1     6   the same vertex in the data we have
    //     \   /    as they don't share UV coords.
    //      S/E
    //
    // the vertices at the start and end do not share vertices
    // since they have different UVs but if you don't consider
    // them to share vertices they will get the wrong normals

    const vertIndices = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
      const offset = i * 3;
      const vert = positions.slice(offset, offset + 3);
      vertIndices.push(getVertIndex(vert));
    }

    // go through every vertex and record which faces it's on
    const vertFaces = [];
    getNextIndex.reset();
    for (let i = 0; i < numFaces; ++i) {
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        const ndx = getNextIndex();
        const sharedNdx = vertIndices[ndx];
        let faces = vertFaces[sharedNdx];
        if (!faces) {
          faces = [];
          vertFaces[sharedNdx] = faces;
        }
        faces.push(i);
      }
    }

    // now go through every face and compute the normals for each
    // vertex of the face. Only include faces that aren't more than
    // maxAngle different. Add the result to arrays of newPositions,
    // newTexcoords and newNormals, discarding any vertices that
    // are the same.
    tempVerts = {};
    tempVertNdx = 0;
    const newPositions = [];
    const newTexcoords = [];
    const newNormals = [];

    function getNewVertIndex(x, y, z, nx, ny, nz, u, v) {
      const vertId =
          x + "," + y + "," + z + "," +
          nx + "," + ny + "," + nz + "," +
          u + "," + v;

      const ndx = tempVerts[vertId];
      if (ndx !== undefined) {
        return ndx;
      }
      const newNdx = tempVertNdx++;
      tempVerts[vertId] = newNdx;
      newPositions.push(x, y, z);
      newNormals.push(nx, ny, nz);
      newTexcoords.push(u, v);
      return newNdx;
    }

    const newVertIndices = [];
    getNextIndex.reset();
    const maxAngleCos = Math.cos(maxAngle);
    // for each face
    for (let i = 0; i < numFaces; ++i) {
      // get the normal for this face
      const thisFaceNormal = faceNormals[i];
      // for each vertex on the face
      for (let j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        const ndx = getNextIndex();
        const sharedNdx = vertIndices[ndx];
        const faces = vertFaces[sharedNdx];
        const norm = [0, 0, 0];
        faces.forEach(faceNdx => {
          // is this face facing the same way
          const otherFaceNormal = faceNormals[faceNdx];
          const dot = m4.dot(thisFaceNormal, otherFaceNormal);
          if (dot > maxAngleCos) {
            m4.addVectors(norm, otherFaceNormal, norm);
          }
        });
        m4.normalize(norm, norm);
        const poffset = ndx * 3;
        const toffset = ndx * 2;
        newVertIndices.push(getNewVertIndex(
            positions[poffset + 0], positions[poffset + 1], positions[poffset + 2],
            norm[0], norm[1], norm[2],
            texcoords[toffset + 0], texcoords[toffset + 1]));
      }
    }

    return {
      position: newPositions,
      texcoord: newTexcoords,
      normal: newNormals,
      indices: newVertIndices,
    };

  }

  function makeIndexedIndicesFn(arrays) {
    const indices = arrays.indices;
    let ndx = 0;
    const fn = function() {
      return indices[ndx++];
    };
    fn.reset = function() {
      ndx = 0;
    };
    fn.numElements = indices.length;
    return fn;
  }

  function makeUnindexedIndicesFn(arrays) {
    let ndx = 0;
    const fn = function() {
      return ndx++;
    };
    fn.reset = function() {
      ndx = 0;
    }
    fn.numElements = arrays.positions.length / 3;
    return fn;
  }

  function makeIndiceIterator(arrays) {
    return arrays.indices
        ? makeIndexedIndicesFn(arrays)
        : makeUnindexedIndicesFn(arrays);
  }
}
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/3d-math.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: thank you very much sir, i'm getting a blank screen running the heighmap image, if you could please take a look at my code in the edit

Comment: based on what do you determine the texture coordinates and what if i wanted to get them from an image?

Comment: What do you mean "get texture coordinates from an image". You don't generally get texture coordinates from an image. [You use them to reference parts of an image](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html). The texture coords in the example are not used. They just spread over the grid an a normal fashion so if you did use them they'd map an image flat on. https://jsfiddle.net/greggman/b6x0su5r/