# How do i do to make wait the program untile an image is load ? (java script)

Tags: javascript

I have recently started to learn html and i'm currently working on java script. My problem is that i would to stop the program until a image as been load for, after that draw the image on a canvas (because if the image is not load and i want to draw it on a canvas, nothing would be display).

Here's my code (put in one file) :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>dog food</title>
        <link rel = "icon" href = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudx87gpctKJdgDyq5DpVlb12fI3_7XgbfXw&usqp=CAU">
        <style>
            canvas.GameWindow {
                display : block;
                margin-left : auto;
                margin-right : auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas width = 600 height = 350 class = GameWindow>Sorry but the canvas is not taken by your web browser</canvas>
        
        <script>
            var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            
            //initialize canvas
            /*ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
             ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 600, 350);*/
            
            //create function
            function drawAnImage(positionX,positionY,width,height,image) {
                ctx.drawImage(image, positionX, positionY, width, height);
                console.log("an image has been drawn");
            };
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudx87gpctKJdgDyq5DpVlb12fI3_7XgbfXw&usqp=CAU";
            img.onload = function() {
                console.log("image load");
            };
            drawAnImage(0,0,100,100,img);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Actually when i run the code, nothing is display on the canvas because the image is load after i call the drawAnImage function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Waiting for image to load in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342132/waiting-for-image-to-load-in-javascript)

Comment: No sorry, in my case it doesnt solve the problem, the code would still run whithout waiting for the image to load. But what i want to stop the program until the image is load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i finaly use this little algorithm for image loading :

```js
const imageToLoad = [];
                var totalImage = imageToLoad.length;
                let imageLoad = [];
                
                for (var i = 0;i<totalImage;i++) {
                    var img = new Image();
                    img.src = imageToLoad[i];
                    imageLoad.push(img);
                    img.onload = function() {
                        if (i == totalImage) {
                            //here i start my game loop
                            gameLoop(imageLoad);
                        };
                    };  
                };
```

So what values is for? The first valu `imageToLoad` is where you would put the images you want to use and `imageLoad` is where you would find your loaded images. Finaly, for the peoples interested in the algorithm, the algorithm would every time an image is load see if it the last image to load, if yes, the algorithm would start in my case the gameloop of the game.

Answer (score 1):

Wait for it to load with a callback:

```js
img.onload = function () {
    drawImage(0, 0, 100, 100, img);
};
```

You can also do something if there was an error loading it:

```js
img.onerror = function () {
    alert("Oh no an error!");
};
```

Here it is with ES6 arrow functions and `addEventListener`:

```js
img.addEventListener("load", () => {
    drawImage(0, 0, 100, 100, img);
});

img.addEventListener("error", () => {
    alert("Oh no an error!");
});
```

Comment: The problem still the same for me. If i use your method, i would need to put fonctions in fonctions and wouldn't be great.

Comment: Well there is a solution called async/await and Promises... but I thought that would be a little too complicated and advanced for you since you just started

Comment: You can still explain me, if doesnt understand some concept i would go search on my own.