# Canvas sprites images only loads after a page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have read the previous posts on this and I understand that the image isn't being loaded initially because I am drawing it before it's loaded, and that when I refresh it, because the browser caches the image it is drawn.

Firsly, I have a `Spritesheet` class:

```js
class Spritesheet
{
    constructor(filename, rows, cols, x, y)
    {
        this.filename  = `./game/static/img/${filename}`;

        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    
        this.spritesheet = new Image();
        this.spritesheet.onload = loadImages(this);
    }

    load()
    {
        this.spritesheet.src = this.filename;
        this.width = this.spritesheet.width / this.rows;
        this.height = this.spritesheet.height / this.cols;
    }

}
```

Then I have the `loadImages` function that call the method `load(spritesheet)`:

```js
function loadImages(spritesheet)
{
    spritesheet.load();
    if (--numOfImages <= 0) loadGame();
    
}
```

Inside my `window.onload` call I have a function called `preloadStatic()` that populates 2 arrays for certain Sprites that the game uses:

```js
function preloadStatic()
{
    var wallSpritesCount = 4;
    var floorSpritesCount = 10;

    numOfImages = wallSpritesCount + floorSpritesCount;
    
    for (let i = 0; i < wallSpritesCount; i++) {
        let filename = `wall/brick_gray_${i}.png`;
        let spritesheet = new Spritesheet(filename, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        wallSprites.push(spritesheet);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < floorSpritesCount; i++) {
        let filename = `floor/white_marble_${i}.png`;
        let spritesheet = new Spritesheet(filename, 1, 1, 0, 0);
        floorSprites.push(spritesheet);
    }
}
```

But the sprites only load after a page refresh.

The logic that I am using it that, when the window loads, it preloads the static files and sets the variable `numOfImages`, when it loops through all the possible sprites I need to be loaded inside the `Spritesheet` constructor it sets a `new Image()` then call the `onload` method. Then inside the `onload` method it calls the `Spritesheet.load()` which set's the source of the image to the filename. Once then this has been called for every `Spritesheet` the variable `numOfImages` is decremented to 0 and the game then loads. But this only works when refreshing the page.

Sorry that I have asked a question that has previously been asked but I couldn't find a solution, I have tried using the `onload` method which has been described multiple time. Thank you for reading this.

Comment: The load only _begins_ when you run `this.spritesheet.src = this.filename;`. But immediately, on the next line, you access `this.spritesheet.width` which should be 0 since the image hasn't loaded asynchronously yet. All code that relies on the sprite(s) needs to be chained from the `onload` handler(s). [Promises](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180709/6243352) are the easiest way to deal with the issue of running one block of code after multiple requests finish, rather than relying on a global counter variable `numOfImages`.

Comment: Try moving `this.spritesheet.src = this.filename;` into the constructor, after `this.spritesheet.onload =`. I would rename `load()` to `onImageLoaded()` or something, since it's handling the load completion rather than initiating it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I just tried moving the `this.spritesheet.src` after the `...onload()` and it has the same behavior. I am currently reading into trying to resolve it with promises.

Comment: The [posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77040160/6243352) correctly identified another issue I missed, which is that `loadImages(this);` is being called immediately and its return value `undefined` is being set as the `onload` handler rather than a function reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You run `loadImage(this)` immediately in the constructor
2. Your image will start loading when you set `src` so you can't do that in the `load` function

```
class Spritesheet
{
    constructor(filename, rows, cols, x, y)
    {
        this.filename  = `./game/static/img/${filename}`;

        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
    
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    
        this.spritesheet = new Image();
        // added `() => `
        this.spritesheet.onload = () => loadImages(this);
        // added line below
        this.spritesheet.src = this.filename;
    }

    load()
    {
        // removed this.spritesheet.src = this.filename;
        this.width = this.spritesheet.width / this.rows;
        this.height = this.spritesheet.height / this.cols;
    }

}
```

Comment: It works, thank you so much sir! I am a bit confused on how the arrow function changed the behavior?

So when I set `spritesheet.src = '...'` then it called the `loadImages(this)`?

Again, thank you for this answer, I am sorry if this was a waste of the communities time.

Comment: You called `loadImages(this)` immediately in the constructor and assigned it's result to the `this.spritesheet.onload`, but `this.spritesheet.onload` should be a function reference, not a function's result

Comment: Note also that it has to be an arrow function rather than a `function`, because the `onload` callback would be automatically bound to the loaded `Image` rather than the `Spritesheet` class (unless `.bind()` is used explicitly on the `function`).