# Finish loading images before display changes?

Tags: reactjs, image, react-hooks, onload, react-lifecycle

I am using React JS. Upon submitting a form, I would like to load all of the 16x16px png images so that I can have and utilize their data (as an array containing 16 arrays, each with 16 values inside) BEFORE `display` is set to 'gameboard' and the next page gets rendered. The loading images part is in the `convertAllLayouts` function.

`layoutShapes` located in `GameSettingsContext` will be set as the loaded image data and, upon clicking the 'Start Game!' button, will then be used by the 'gameboard' display.

I tried having `useEffect` load the images, but it still loads the images after the 'gameboard' display component is rendered. Perhaps waiting to load the image has something to do with it?

Here is my code:

```
import { useState, useContext, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

import { GameSettingsContext, DisplayContext, AllCustomLayoutShapesContext } from "../../Game";

export default function CustomGameOptions() {
    const canvasRef = useRef('canvas#layout-canvas');

    const {display, setDisplay} = useContext(DisplayContext);

    const [isCustomLayoutShapesSubmitClicked, setIsCustomLayoutShapesSubmitClicked] = useState(false)

    const 
    {
        layoutShapes,
        setLayoutShapes,
    } = useContext(GameSettingsContext);

    const {
        presetLayouts, 
        setPresetLayouts, 
    } = useContext(AllCustomLayoutShapesContext);

    function convertAllLayouts(ref, presets) {
        let convertedPresets = [];
        let convertedLayouts = [];

        if (presetLayouts.length > 0) {

            for (let presetIndex = 0; presetIndex < presetLayouts.length; presetIndex++) {
                let newConvertedPreset = [];

                let img = new Image();
                img.crossOrigin='Anonymous';
                
                let ctx = canvasRef.current.getContext('2d', { alpha: true, desynchronized: false, colorSpace: 'srgb', willReadFrequently: true})
                ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";

                let imageData;

                img.onload = function () {

                    ctx.width = img.width;
                    ctx.height = img.height;
                    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                    
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                    imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 16, 16, {colorSpace: 'srgb'}).data;
                    for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 16; rowIndex++) {

                        let newRow = [];
                        
                        for (let i = 0 + 64 * rowIndex; i < 64 + 64 * rowIndex; i += 4) {
                            // every 4th imageData element is 
                            // the alpha channel for each pixel

                            if (imageData[i + 3] === 255) {
                                newRow.push(1);
                            } else if (imageData[i + 3] === 0) {
                                newRow.push(0);
                            }

                        }
                        newConvertedPreset.push(newRow)
                    }
                    convertedPresets.push(newConvertedPreset)
                }
                img.src = presetLayouts[presetIndex]
            }
        }

        convertedLayouts = [...convertedPresets]
        return convertedLayouts;
    }


    function handleClick(event) {
            setIsCustomLayoutShapesSubmitClicked(true)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isCustomLayoutShapesSubmitClicked === true) {
            const layouts = convertAllLayouts(canvasRef, presetLayouts)

            if (layouts.length === 0) {

                let defaultLayoutShape = []

                for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < tileDimensions.h; rowIndex++) {

                    const newRow = new Array(tileDimensions.w).fill(1);

                    if ((tileDimensions.h * tileDimensions.w) % 2 !== 0) {
                        if (rowIndex === Math.floor(tileDimensions.h / 2)) {
                            newRow[Math.floor(tileDimensions.w / 2)] = 0;
                        }
                    } 
                    defaultLayoutShape.push(newRow);

                }
                setLayoutShapes([defaultLayoutShape, 'default']);
            }

            setLayoutShapes([...layouts]);
            setIsCustomLayoutShapesSubmitClicked(false)
            setDisplay('gameboard');

        }
    }, [isCustomLayoutShapesSubmitClicked])

    return (
        <article>
            <canvas id="layout-canvas" ref={canvasRef} width="16" height="16"></canvas>

            <button className="start-game-button" onClick={handleClick}>Start Game!</button>
        </article>
    )
}
```

Apologies for the lengthy block of code, I tried to trim it up a bit.

If anyone might know of what could be causing this issue, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly does "loading" mean to you here in this context? Can you clarify, possibly in an [edit] if lengthy?

Comment: I mean loading as in the img.onload event

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you basically want to hide the canvas until all the images have loaded? When do these images actually get loaded now? Sorry, I'm not too familiar with working with the canvas, it's been a few years.

Comment: It's not the canvas I want to hide, I want to prevent the changing of the display from the CustomGameOptions component to the Gameboard component before completing img.onload for every png I have inside presetLayouts.

Comment: I am also not very sure about when the images get loaded, but I know that the source of the image should be provided right after the .onload callback function, and from within the .onload callback function I work with the image data.

Comment: I don't fully get your general idea/issue but, what I can see from your explanation, obviously, you should combine [`Suspence`](https://react.dev/reference/react/Suspense) and the promises to wait until all the images are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I thought that doing .onload would be enough to wait to get the image data in order to then do whatever with it, but it turns out Promises do a better job at ensuring that the image data is there when it is needed.

I followed what this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66180709/18628118) said, and applied it to my own code:

```
const convertPresets = async function (ref, presetLayouts) {
        let convertedLayouts = [];

        if (presetLayouts.length > 0) {

            for (let presetIndex = 0; presetIndex < presetLayouts.length; presetIndex++) {

                let newConvertedPreset = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                    const preset = [];

                    let img = new Image();
                    img.crossOrigin='Anonymous';
                    
                    let ctx = ref.current.getContext('2d', { alpha: true, desynchronized: false, colorSpace: 'srgb', willReadFrequently: true})
                    ctx.translate(16, 16)
                    ctx.rotate(Math.PI)
                    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "copy";

                    let imageData;

                    img.onload = async function () {

                        ctx.width = img.width;
                        ctx.height = img.height;
                        ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
                        
                        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
                        imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 16, 16, {colorSpace: 'srgb'}).data;
                        for (let rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 16; rowIndex++) {

                            let newRow = [];
                            
                            for (let i = 0 + 64 * rowIndex; i < 64 + 64 * rowIndex; i += 4) {
                                // every 4th imageData element is 
                                // the alpha channel for each pixel

                                if (imageData[i + 3] === 255) {
                                    newRow.push(1);
                                } else if (imageData[i + 3] === 0) {
                                    newRow.push(0);
                                }

                            }

                            preset.push(newRow)

                        }

                        resolve(preset)

                    }

                    img.src = presetLayouts[presetIndex];

                }).then(data => data)

                convertedLayouts.push(newConvertedPreset);

            }

        }

        return convertedLayouts;

    }
```

And when I needed to execute this function, I simply did this:

```
const convertedPresetLayouts = await convertPresets(
   canvasRef,
   presetLayouts
)
.then((data) => data);
```

And the data was ready to be used for the next steps!